# Downloading Image Service Tiles

Tags: arcgis-server, image-service, arcgis-image-server

I have an image service connection which I'm trying to download individual tiles from.

Using ArcMap 10.5, I've selected a tile from the attribute table, right-clicked the image service > Data > Download Selected Rasters... and I get the following error message (see image below).

> Failed to retrieve the download files for the list request.

Am I doing something wrong related to the image service permissions?

The Esri help site does not address this error and I could not find a relevant forums that address this issue as well.

[image]

Comment: can you give the url you are connecting to? If the version of the imageservice is higher than your version of ArcMap there maybe compatibility issues. Do you have other option ArcPro? or QGIS?

Comment: This is the link:
http://imagery.oregonexplorer.info/arcgis/rest/services/OSIP_2018/OSIP_2018_SL/ImageServer
I do have access to QGIS, but I'm still learning how to use it. Would using it make any difference?

Answer (score 1):

No issue in QGIS using Web Mapping Service (WMS)

using this url

> `http://imagery.oregonexplorer.info/arcgis/services/OSIP_2018/OSIP_2018_SL/ImageServer/WMSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS`

and added to QGIS (3.8)
[image]

It can also be save as a geotiff (etc) using 'Export' on the layer in QGIS.

Comment: I was able to view the service in QGIS. Now, is there a way to download individual tiles?

Comment: most likely you need to use a script like https://github.com/Luqqk/wms-tiles-downloader

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to solve the error I got (downloading specific tiles) but, I was able to figure out how to download specific areas I needed:

The image service provider allows only to download 15,000 px by 4,100 px area at one time. So, I created a graphic box that size and using the Export Data tool (and using the graphic as a clip) I'm exporting one tile at a time, following a linear shape.
It's not the best solution (I have 250 tiles to download), but it works. Later on I will mosaic the tiles into one TIFF file.

UPDATE: after contacting the service image provider, I was told that they do not "providing a download option". So that could be the reason I'm receiving that error message.